# Print statements giving Invalid Syntax error

Tags: python

this seems to be a little strange. I am having some print statements in my python script which I run via Batch job.

The problem is with the print statements I tried every thing possible but its still throwing a Invalid Syntax error.

```
print STDERR 'Kapil >> BEFORE INSERT';
print STDERR 'Kapil tag_id >> $tag_id';
print STDERR 'Kapil Hostname >> $hostname';
```

I have to give STDERR to print the statements in job out file. Otherwise nothing is getting printed.

```
  File "/d/home/aprun-prologue/aprun-prologue", line 169
    print STDERR 'Kapil >> BEFORE INSERT \n';
                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Thanks,
Kapil

Comment: It looks like you copied Perl code and then expected it to work in Python.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import sys

print >>sys.stderr, 'Kapil >> BEFORE INSERT'
print >>sys.stderr, 'Kapil tag_id >> $tag_id'
print >>sys.stderr, 'Kapil Hostname >> $hostname'
```

Comment: tried this but again nothing is showing up in my output file

Comment: We aren't sure if the OP is using python2 or python3, so this would not work for them on python3.  If python3, they would need `print('Kapil >> BEFORE INSERT', file=sys.stderr)`

Comment: Also, assuming they did in fact copy Perl code and expect it to work, they probably need to put the variables into the strings, so they should be doing `'Kapil tag_id >> {}'.format(tag_id)'` to get the exact same result.

Comment: @user2907995 Unless you are piping stderr to a file when you call this script, this output would print to the screen, not a file (stderr is not a file).

Comment: I am piping stderr to a file. The flow of the job is, its first calling a perl script which calls a python script. Whatever prints statements (STDERR) that I give in perl script are showing up in the stderr file but not the python ones. btw its python 2.6 which is installed and not 3.0 (i checked this too @Seth)

Comment: Is your perl script capturing the output of your python script?